# R shiny does not show expected output or errors

Tags: r, shiny

I am new using R shiny.
I want to make an app that reads in a csv, performs some operations to create a data.frame and then output a plot given an id.

Here is the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(readxl)
library(ggenealogy)
library(ggplot2)
library(collapsibleTree)

datos = read_xlsx("file.xlsx", sheet = 1)
'%!in%' = function(x,y)!('%in%'(x,y))

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Buscar genealogía"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("Search dendrogram for a given ID"),
      
      textInput("bidi", 
                  label = "Write ID:",
                  value = "PL1804160067"),
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("grafica")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$grafica <- renderPlot({
    
    grafico = plotAncDes(input$bidi, datos, 9, 9)
    datos2 = grafico$data
    
    if ("ancestor" %in% datos2$type){
      ancestros = datos2[datos2$type == "ancestor",]
      n_ancestros = nrow(ancestros)
      generaciones = sort(unique(datos2$genside))
      rows_final = nrow(datos2[datos2$genside == 1,])
      final = data.frame(matrix(ncol = length(generaciones), nrow = rows_final))
      colnames(final) = generaciones
      n_generaciones = length(which(generaciones > 0))
      for (n_ancestro in 1:ncol(final)){
        if (as.numeric(colnames(final)[n_ancestro]) < 0){
          final[, n_ancestro] = datos2$label[which(datos2$genside == colnames(final)[n_ancestro])]
        }
      }
      final[, "0"] = input$bidi
      hijos = getChild(input$bidi, datos)
      final[, "1"] = hijos
      
      
      generacion = 1
      if (max(generaciones) - generacion > 0){
        quedan_generaciones = TRUE  
      }
      else {
        quedan_generaciones = FALSE 
      }
      while (quedan_generaciones){
        for (muestra in unique(final[, as.character(generacion)])){
          nuevos_hijos = getChild(muestra, datos)
          if (length(nuevos_hijos > 0)){
            subdataset = final[which(final[, as.character(generacion)] == muestra),]
            fila_copiar = subdataset
            for (i in 1:(length(nuevos_hijos) -1)){
              subdataset = rbind(subdataset, fila_copiar)
            }
            subdataset[, as.character(generacion + 1)] = nuevos_hijos
            final = final[-which(final[, as.character(generacion)] == muestra),]
            final = rbind(final, subdataset)
          }
        }
        generacion = generacion + 1
        if (generacion > max(generaciones)){
          quedan_generaciones = FALSE
        }
      }
    }
    
    if ("ancestor" %!in% datos2$type){
      generaciones = sort(unique(datos2$genside))
      rows_final = nrow(datos2[datos2$genside == 1,])
      final = data.frame(matrix(ncol = length(generaciones), nrow = rows_final))
      colnames(final) = generaciones
      n_generaciones = length(which(generaciones > 0))
      
      final[, "0"] = input$bidi
      hijos = getChild(input$bidi, datos)
      final[, "1"] = hijos
      
      
      generacion = 1
      if (max(generaciones) - generacion > 0){
        quedan_generaciones = TRUE  
      }
      else {
        quedan_generaciones = FALSE 
      }
      while (quedan_generaciones){
        for (muestra in unique(final[, as.character(generacion)])){
          nuevos_hijos = getChild(muestra, datos)
          if (length(nuevos_hijos > 0)){
            subdataset = final[which(final[, as.character(generacion)] == muestra),]
            fila_copiar = subdataset
            for (i in 1:(length(nuevos_hijos) - 1)){
              subdataset = rbind(subdataset, fila_copiar)
            }
            subdataset[, as.character(generacion + 1)] = nuevos_hijos
            final = final[-which(final[, as.character(generacion)] == muestra),]
            final = rbind(final, subdataset)
          }
        }
        generacion = generacion + 1
        if (generacion > max(generaciones)){
          quedan_generaciones = FALSE
        }
      }
    }
    
    collapsibleTree(final, hierarchy = colnames(final))

  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The code seems to work without the use of shiny. Interestingly, when I close the app, the actual plot is displayed on the RStudio plot section. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: From the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/collapsibleTree/collapsibleTree.pdf) for the collapsibleTree package, it looks like you need `collapsibleTreeOutput` and `renderCollapsibleTree`, not `plotOutput` and `renderPlot`.  As an aside, I feel it is always a good idea to separate data manipulation from data analysis and presentation of results.  If I have a `renderXXXX` that's more than two or three statements long, I feel it's time to refactor.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Limey, now it works nicely! How can I separate the part of the code for the data manipulation? Are modules in shiny intended for that?

Comment: Glad to have helped.  No you don't need modules.  Simply break down the construction of the tree into separate steps.  Put each step into a separate `reactive`.  Make sure each step depends on the previous.  My generic acronym is IWARD: Ingestion, Wrangling, Analysis, Reporting, Documentation.  Each part of the process is conducted separately (eg in its own function/reactive).  Complex steps may well have sub-functions.